# Switch statement prematurely closing

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm currently working on a project for a university course, and I'm having issues with a switch statement ending prematurely. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

It's supposed to take the user's input, and if not one of the cases, restart the switch statement. However, as soon as one invalid char is put in, the switch statement closes completely and ends the program.

I currently have it set to print out each code if it enters correctly, however,

```
public static void companyClassificationCode() {
    char companyCode;

    System.out.print("Please enter your company classification code: ");
    companyCode = console.next().charAt(0);
    switch (companyCode) {
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            System.out.println("C");
            companyCode = 'C';
            break;
        case 'l':
        case 'L':
            System.out.println("L");
            companyCode = 'L';
            break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            System.out.println("N");
            companyCode = 'N';
            break;
        case 's':
        case 'S':
            System.out.println("S");
            companyCode = 'S';
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("An invalid code has been entered. Please enter your company classification code: ");

    }
}
```

Comment: You currently haven't written any code to 'restart the switch statement'. You'll either need to wrap everything in a loop, or you could actually call `companyClassificationCode` again in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to wrap the `switch` statement in a loop.
The following code will loop until a valid code is entered; invalid values are reverted to the initial value (a single space character) and the loop is restarted.

```java
    public static void companyClassificationCode() {
        char companyCode = ' ';

        while (companyCode == ' ') {
            System.out.print("Please enter your company classification code: ");
            companyCode = console.next().charAt(0);
            switch (companyCode) {
                case 'c':
                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("C");
                    companyCode = 'C';
                    break;
                case 'l':
                case 'L':
                    System.out.println("L");
                    companyCode = 'L';
                    break;
                case 'n':
                case 'N':
                    System.out.println("N");
                    companyCode = 'N';
                    break;
                case 's':
                case 'S':
                    System.out.println("S");
                    companyCode = 'S';
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("An invalid code has been entered. Please enter your company classification code: ");
                    companyCode = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: IntelliJ is saying that char companyCode isn't initialized if I run the while loop where you suggested.

Comment: `while (companyCode == ' ') { ... }` won't keep it in a loop if the user enters an invalid char. If the user enters 'A' then the loop would stop executing. An easy workaround would just be to assign `companyCode = ' ';` in the `default` case.

Comment: Use a `do { … } while(…);` loop and you don’t need to pre-initialize the `companyCode`. For example `char companyCode;  do {System.out.print("Please enter your company classification code: ");  companyCode = Character.toUpperCase(console.next().charAt(0)); } 
 while("CNLS".indexOf(companyCode) == -1);`